# How can convert a dictionary file (.dic) with an affix file (.aff) to create a list of words?

Tags: dictionary

Im looking at a dictionary file (".dic") and its associated "aff" file.  What I'm trying to do is combine the rules in the "aff" file with the words in the "dic" file to create a global list of all words contained within the dictionary file.

The documentation behind these files is difficult to find.  Does anyone know of a resource that I can learn from?

Is there any code out there that will already do this (am I duplicating an effort that I don't need to)?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to [Pillowcase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2424121/pillowcase), here it's an example of usage:

```
# Download dictionary
wget -O ./dic/es_ES.aff "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sbosio/rla-es/master/source-code/hispalabras-0.1/hispalabras/es_ES.aff"
wget -O ./dic/es_ES.dic "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sbosio/rla-es/master/source-code/hispalabras-0.1/hispalabras/es_ES.dic"

# Compile program
wget -O ./dic/unmunch.cxx "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hunspell/hunspell/master/src/tools/unmunch.cxx"
wget -O ./dic/unmunch.h "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hunspell/hunspell/master/src/tools/unmunch.h"
g++ -o ./dic/unmunch ./dic/unmunch.cxx

# Generate dictionary
./dic/unmunch ./dic/es_ES.dic ./dic/es_ES.aff 2> /dev/null > ./dic/es_ES.txt.bk
sort ./dic/es_ES.txt.bk > ./dic/es_ES.txt # Opcional
rm ./dic/es_ES.txt.bk # Opcional
```

Comment: Great! I share the generated file (it's unsorted) for those whom want a **unmunched spanish dictionary** and have not access to a linux terminal: [es_ES.txt](https://www.4shared.com/office/PL_9bh_diq/es_ES.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need a utility called munch.exe to apply the aff rules to the dic file.

Answer (score 2):

These could be [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) dictionary files. Unfortunately, the command to create a "global" or unmunched wordlist only fully support simple .aff and .dic files.

From [the documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/).

```
unmunch: list all recognized words of a MySpell dictionary
```

Syntax:

```
unmunch dic_file affix_file
```

Try it and see what happens. For generating all wordforms for one word only, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725861/generate-all-word-forms-using-lucene-hunspell/16897264#16897264).

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, the command-line program `unmunch`, from Hunspell, supposedly does what you want. However this program is outdated and very buggy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725861/generate-all-word-forms-using-lucene-hunspell/#66661578) for more detail and alternatives.